# op_behavior_selector node seems to be invalid

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
op_behavior_selector node seems to be invalid. I don't know why and how to solve it.

1. environment: autoware.ai.1.13 melodic
2. issue：op_local_selected_trajectory topic publish the optimal path within a period of time after starting the op_behavior_selector node.After a while, the op_behavior_selector node seems to be invalid, no longer with the obstacle to update the path, while the op_trajectory_evaluator still evaluates the optimal path.In this case, launch the pure_pursuit node, the vehicle failed to avoid the obstacle and stopped in front of the obstacle.
3. video: https://youtu.be/f2wJttduOO8
   Can you give me some guidance suggestions ? @Hatem
   Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396261/op_behavior_selector-node-seems-to-be-invalid/) by [Jason_Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/97060/jason_chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is by design.

Lane change is disabled when local trajectory length is smaller than the distance to goal pose.

if you try longer global path, or shorted local trajectory (local planning distance). this will work as expected.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jason_Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/97060/jason_chen/) on 2022-02-17**:
Indeed, the problem has been solved after adjusting the parameters, thank you very much.

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2022-02-17**:
Great, can you mark this as an answered question so others can benefit from it.